# Update Anaconda Notebook package get failed -

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

On my local server I installed Anaconda 3.4 (python 3.5). The jupyter-notebook version on Anaconda is Notebook 4.2.3 and I want to update this to 5.0.0

Seeing that I'm not connected to internet, so I downloaded the package from Anaconda repository: https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/ to My local machine and then to the server.

I've done the following commands to update the package on the server (`/opt/Anaconda`):

```
mkdir -p /opt/Anaconda/channel/linux64
conda index /opt/Anaconda/channel/linux64
cp /tmp/notebook-5.0.0.tar.tar /opt/Anaconda/channel/linux64
conda install /opt/Anaconda/channel/linux64/notebook-5.0.0.tar.tar
```

when I've displayed the anaconda package list `conda list` I've noticed that the version is still 4.2.3

Any help please!

Comment: Can you try `conda install --offline notebook-5.0.0.tar.bz2`?

Comment: @darthbith it works now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command should include the `--offline` flag. You also do not need to copy the package file to any particular folder, installing from wherever you downloaded the tar file should work too:

```
conda install --offline /opt/Anaconda/channel/linux64/notebook-5.0.0.tar.bz2
```